# Calculating the depth of an element in an associative array with php

Tags: php, recursion, associative-array

I've been trying unsuccessfully to write a recursive function to give me the depth of a given element.  I just can't seem to get my head around the recursion.  This is what I have, but it's not working correctly:

```
function getDepth($a, $e, $depth = 0) {
  foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      if ($key == $e) {
        return $depth;
      }
      return getDepth($val, $e, $depth + 1);
    }
    else {
      if ($val == $e) {
        return $depth;
      }
      else {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help point out what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:

@Brad @Amber @Viktor Thanks, but this doesn't seem to be working either. Here's what I'm after... I have an array that looks like this:

```
[antonio] => Array
(
    [ian] => Array
        (
            [molly] => Array
                (
                    [blake] => blake
                )

        )

    [shonda] => Array
        (
            [dana] => dana
            [james] => james
        )

    [nels] => Array
        (
            [jason] => jason
            [danny] => danny
        )

    [molly] => Array
        (
            [blake] => blake
        )

    [blake] => blake
    [travis] => travis
)
```

It's a tree, and I'm hoping to find the depth level of a given name. So, I'll need to pass in a name, say blake. Then I'll want to traverse the whole tree keeping track of blake's depth whenever I find it as he could be (and indeed is in this example) in the tree at different levels. Assuming that the top-most depth level is 0, blake's level under antonio => ian => molly => blake is 3, but his level under antonio => blake is 1, so I would want to return 1. I will have to traverse the entire tree (luckily this function will not be called very often) to make sure that I've found the most shallow depth in the tree for the given user. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Define 'not working correctly'? Whenever you ask a question like this, you should specify what you're expecting and what you're getting instead.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to get the recursion right, if you know you have an array within your function, run your same function on it.  We add the deepest path so far +1.  In the end, you get what you are looking for.

```
function getDepth($a) {
    $max=0;
    foreach ($a as $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $tmp_depth=getDepth($val);
            if ($max<($tmp_depth)) {
                $max=$tmp_depth;
            }
        }
    }
    return $max+1;
}
```

I haven't benchmarked this or anything.  Undoubtedly there could be speed improvements, if it is important.

Comment: @JamesAndino, Ha, thanks.  It is actually a WiFi-repeating corn cob hat.  Inside it is a directional yagi pointed out the front, a cut up Linksys WAP54g, and a small omni hanging off the back.  You put the hat on, and there is a switch inside which powers up the WAP, and point at some other WAP off in the distance.  I sold it years ago, but I've always missed that thing...

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDepth($a, $e, $depth = 0) {
  $lower  = false;   //  meaning 'not found'
  // as you are looking for the less deep value, first check for values and then for arrays
  // so there are chances when you do not traverse all the tree for a match
  foreach ($a as $key => $val) if ($val == $e) return $depth;
  foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      $tmp = getDepth($val, $e, $depth + 1);
      if($tmp) if ($lower === false || $tmp < $lower) $lower = $tmp;
    }
  }
  return $lower;
}

$x=array( 
  antonio => Array(
    ian => Array(
       molly => Array(
          blake => blake,
          jhonyDeep => jhonyDeep
       )
    ),
    shonda => Array(
       dana => dana,
       james => james
    ),
    nels => Array (
       jason => jason,
       danny => danny
    ),
    molly => Array(
       blake => blake
    ),
    blake => blake,
    travis => travis
  )
);


echo getDepth($x, blake);      // gives 1
echo getDepth($x, danny);      // gives 2
echo getDepth($x, jhonyDeep);  // gives 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't get the most shallow depth for element $e.  In the example from before, this would return depth = 3 for kale, when his most shallow depth would be depth = 1.  I need to store the depth in some sort of temporary variable as I continue to traverse the rest of the tree.  If I find another depth for the element, $e -- then I compare it to the previous one saved in the temp variable saving the smallest of the two into that same temp variable.  Once I've traversed the whole tree, then I return the temp variable.  But how to do this with recursion?

Comment: Thanks @LuisSiquot!  This is really close, but there is still an issue with this algorithm.  `echo getDepth($x, 'ian')` returns false, as does any non-leaf node in the tree.  That is to say that from the above array `$x`, only blake, jhonyDeep, dana, james, jason, danny and travis return have valid depth values returned while antonio, ian, molly, shonda and nels (parent nodes) all have false returned as their depth.  The problem seems to be with the `foreach ($a as $key => $val) if ($val == $e) return $depth` line, as this will only return the $depth if the value is NOT an array.  Thoughts?

Comment: yes it is, you can do `if ($key == $e) return $depth;` or `if ($val== $e || $key == $e) return $depth;` as you need. did you see my other version?

Answer (score 0):

similar to my previous anwser but optimized for performance (and be careful, not tested)

```
function getDepth($a, $e, $depth = 0, $lower = false) {
  // $lower = false means 'not found'
  // as you are looking for the less deep value, first check for values and then for arrays
  // so there are chances when you do not traverse all the tree for a match
  foreach ($a as $key => $val) if ($val == $e) return $depth;
  foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      $tmp = false;
      if($lower===false || $lower > $depth) $tmp = getDepth($val, $e, $depth + 1, $lower);  // to do not recurse innecesary
      if($tmp) {
        if($tmp==$depth+1) return $tmp;  //optimization: $depth+1 can't be beat by other values
        if ($lower === false || $tmp < $lower) $lower = $tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return $lower;
}

$x=array( 
  antonio => Array(
    ian => Array(
       molly => Array(
          blake => blake,
          jhonyDeep => jhonyDeep
       )
    ),
    shonda => Array(
       dana => dana,
       james => james
    ),
    nels => Array (
       jason => jason,
       danny => danny
    ),
    molly => Array(
       blake => blake
    ),
    blake => blake,
    travis => travis
  )
);


echo getDepth($x, blake);      // gives 1
echo getDepth($x, danny);      // gives 2
echo getDepth($x, jhonyDeep);  // gives 3
```